# Motoko Upgrade Actor Class Canister

Tags: motoko, internet-computer

I am utilizing `actor classes` within my motoko app that are created dynamically. How do I upgrade those canisters using `dfx`.

When using `dfx deploy` it only upgrades the static `actor` canisters, not any of my dynamically created `actor classes`.

## Update 1:

I have found the `IC` management canister can install new code on other canisters with webassembly bytes, but am unsure how to get that new code to update the actor class instances

What is the proper way of rolling out updates to all dynamically created actor classes that are deployed already?

## Example

Main.mo

```
import A "ActorClass";
import Array "mo:base/Array";
import Cycles "mo:base/ExperimentalCycles";


actor MainCanister {

    var created_canisters : [A.ActorClass] = [];

    public func create_player() : async A.ActorClass {
        let canister : A.ActorClass = await A.ActorClass();
        created_canisters := Array.append(created_canisters, [canister]);
        return canister;
    };
};
```

ActorClass.mo

```
actor class ActorClass() {

}
```

### Step 1: Deploy

MainCainster is installed as expected

### Step 2: Call `create_player` func

A instance/canister of ActorClass is created

### Step 3: Update ActorClass with new/changed functionality

### Step 4: Re-Deploy

ONLY MainCanister is updated, not any ActorClass instance

---

Comment: could you provide some basic example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 0):

check this thread. it explains how to upgrade child canisters with a node script and a management canister.

https://forum.dfinity.org/t/how-do-i-upgrade-child-canisters-that-were-dynamically-created-from-a-parent-canister-of-which-i-am-the-controlller-in-motoko/12289/4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).